# What type of reaction is the reaction between an acid and a carbonate?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, terminology, decomposition

Consider the following reaction:

$$\ce{2HCl + Na2CO3 -> 2NaCl + H2O + CO2}$$

Is this a double displacement reaction or a decomposition reaction?

Comment: Does it have to be one or the other?

Answer (score 3):

The first step is a proton transfer (acid-base reaction), from HCl to carbonate, to produce hydrogen carbonate ion. The second step is also a proton transfer, from HCl to hydrogen carbonate to produce carbonic acid. The third step (or maybe better described as a two-step acid-catalyzed process) is the dehydration of carbonic acid to carbon dioxide and water.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is both. A very hand-waving explanation is the following process:
$$\ce{2HCl + Na2CO3 -> 2NaCl + H2CO3 -> 2NaCl + H2O + CO2}$$
The double displacement of $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{Na}$ occurs between the $\ce{Na2CO3}$ and $\ce{HCl}$.  Since the $\ce{H2CO3}$ product is unstable it will decompose at the high concentration to produce water and carbon dioxide.

A more thermodynamic explanation is that first the reactants dissociate into their conjugate acids and bases.  The $\ce{H+}$, $\ce{NaCO3-}$, and eventual $\ce{HCO3-}$ ions will interact in various proportions to form a equillibrium. The equillibrium between $\ce{CO2}$ gas and water with the aqueous $\ce{H2CO3}$ is important: 
$$\ce{H2CO3_{(aq)} <-> H2O_{(l)} + CO2_{,(g)} }$$
The equillibrium will be dictated by the vapor pressure of $\ce{CO2}$:and the concentration of carbonic acid:
$$K_\mathrm{eq} = \frac{[p_{\ce{CO2}}]_\mathrm{eq}}{[\ce{H2CO3}]_\mathrm{eq}} \qquad Q = \frac{[p_{\ce{CO2}}]}{[\ce{H2CO3}]}$$
If the concentration of $\ce{H2CO3}$ is too high we will get: $Q<K$ and thus  more $\ce{CO2}$ must be produced to acheive equillibrium.